# how to abort requests in Puppeteer with a timeout

Tags: javascript, headless, puppeteer, google-chrome-headless

When taking screenshots with Puppeteer I notice that some aren't taken because a script on the website takes to long to load which triggers the `goTo` timeout (after 60 secs). I can't increase the timeout any more and even if I did some scripts still don't load because they hang.

How can I `abort` scripts which take to long to load??

I think I would like to `abort` scripts after around 20 seconds.

```
await page.setRequestInterception(true);

page.on('request', request => {

    if (request.resourceType() == "script") {
        // abort script if it takes longer than 20 seconds to load
    }

});
```

Comment: you can use the timeout property of goto: page.goto(site, {timeout: 15000});. This is setting a timeout for the request of 15sec. Or, if you wanna to take the screenshot, you can use the waitFor function.

Comment: I already have a 60-second timeout on the `goTo` and can't change it because if I set it any lower it will cause other problems in my script. I need to abort scripts after 20 seconds.

Comment: any updates? I want to control certain request, not only whole page load

Comment: @turrican_34 were you able to solve this?

Comment: @Sibi John, No, unfortunately not. According to the Puppeteer devs "there's no such fine-grained control in the devtools protocol,". https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/2316 I did write an ad blocker in puppeteer though which helps and also blocks some other scripts which are not requires like analytics, tagmanager etc